# Is there a C library reference available from the command line?

Tags: c, xcode, command-line, prompt

I am taking a C language class at the university. Generally, I use xCode to write my programs. However, it looks like for the midterm and lab tests I will have to use a simple text editor, because they do not have any IDE for C installed on their computers over there.

So, I was wondering if there is any way to simulate xCode's prompts with the command line. I mean, something like being able to look up all the .h files I can #include and the functions they contain, so that I don't have to memorize things like `#include ctype.h`, `fgets(<#char *restrict#>, <#int#>, <#FILE *#>)`, etc.

I tried googling, but could not find anything.

Comment: Do they allow you to use any references during the test?

Comment: You haven't said a thing about what *will* be available on the machines.  You'll probably at least have `man fgets`.

Comment: @indiv I never knew there were man pages for standard library functions. Very cool.

Comment: @SimpleJ:  Right on.  `man man` will show you what's available.  Library functions are in section 3, so technically you should specify the section.  Like `man printf` will show you the shell printf, but `man 3 printf` will show you the C library function printf.

Comment: I've just tried man fgets. This is exactly what I wanted to find. Now, how can I see whats in the entire C library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man` pages are accessible from the command line and document library calls in section 3.  As an example, `man 3 fgets` will show you everything you need to know about `fgets`, including its header, function signature, and description.

Type `man man` to read more about man pages.

To see all pages in section 3, you can use `apropos`.

**Ubuntu Linux:**

```
apropos -s 3 .
```

You can filter that list a bit by knowing all C library functions start with a lowercase letter:

```
apropos -s 3 . | grep ^[a-z]
```

**OS X:**

On OS X, apropose appears to take only a keyword.  So if you tell it `(3)`, it will list everything in man section 3.  And of course you can `grep` to filter it to everything starting with a lowercase letter.

```
apropos '(3)' | grep ^[a-z]
```

**Portable:**

[`man -k`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/man.html) should be supported by every system.  It takes a keyword to search for, and you can provide `.` to mean match everything.

```
man -k . | grep '^[a-z].*(3)'
```

Comment: I tried the above command and get 
"apropos: -s: unknown option"

Comment: Works for me, _without_ the `-s`, on CentOS 5.

Comment: @user3614293:  I presume you're on OS X because of XCode, right?  I added a command you can use in OS X.  It still lists many system-specific functions, but I don't know how to get it to show only standard C library functions.